# How to restart tomcat 6 in ubuntu

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu

How can one restart and start Tomcat 6  on Ubuntu from the command line with a default installation?

Comment: `sudo service tomcat6 restart`

Comment: sudo systemctl restart tomcat6 or replace the version of your tomcat i.e tomact8 or tomcat9 or only tomcat as per your case

Answer (score 134, accepted):

if you are using extracted tomcat then,

`startup.sh` and `shutdown.sh` are two script located in TOMCAT/bin/ to start and shutdown tomcat, You could use that

if tomcat is installed then

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat5.5 start
/etc/init.d/tomcat5.5 stop
/etc/init.d/tomcat5.5 restart
```

Comment: If tomcat was installed as a service, you can also try `service tomcat6 {stop|start|restart}`

Comment: @ChrisWhite How to differentiate if tomcat is installed as service or otherwise?

Comment: Depends on your *nix install - what are you running on?

Comment: This also works for Debian.

Comment: @ChrisWhite's comment should be a valid answer too

Comment: you can also use $ sudo systemctl start|restart|stop tomcat6 - replace tomcat6 with your version i.e tomcat8 or tomcat9 or tomcat as per your case